Is it possible to disable *only* the “Mouse Battery Low” notification, without disabling other power notifications?
I’m using a wireless mouse, with a battery that will last several more months.
When using Ubuntu, I keep getting “Mouse Battery Low” notifications.
Is there any way to disable only that notification?
The only solutions I’ve found, from several years ago, were to turn off all power notifications (e.g. here and here).
Is it still impossible to disable just the mouse battery notification, while keeping other power notifications enabled?

Change the batteries comes to mind.
